# SQL Server query

Tags: sql-server, select

I have this simple (NON PRACTICAL) table

```
STUDENTID   SERVICE
1           a         
1           b         
1           c         
1           d         
1           e         
2           a         
2           b         
2           c         
2           d          
2           e         
3           a          
3           b         
3           c         
4           a         
4           f         
5           a         
5           d         
6           f         
6           g         
7           a         
7           b         
7           c         
7           d         
7           e         
8           a         
8           b         
8           c         
8           d         
8           e
```

I want to tabulate certain information for instance.

How many students have signed up for service 'a' and service 'b' alone.
How many students have signed up for service 'a' and service 'c' alone.
How many students have signed up for service 'a' and service 'd' alone.  etc.

or

How many students have signed up for service 'a' and one other service other than 'a'.
How many students have signed up for service 'b' and two  other services other than 'b'.

The number of services might change in the future but that's okay for now.

this is what i have right now and it's not working.

--want to return number of students who have signed up for a and 1 any other service

```
select COUNT(STUDENTID), service from table 
group by service where service = 'a' and studentid in 
(select studentid from table group by STUDENTID having COUNT(service) = 2)
```

Comment: What is the question you are asking?

Comment: Based on the table - How many students have signed up for service 'a' and one other service other than 'a'. or

How many students have signed up for service 'b' and two other services other than 'b'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some hints regarding your question.

**How many students have signed up for service 'a' and service 'b' alone.**

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
(
    SELECT studentID
    FROM   tableName
    WHERE  Service IN ('A', 'B')
    GROUP BY StudentID
    HAVING COUNT(studentID) = 2
) a
```

**How many students have signed up for service 'a' and service 'c' alone.**

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
(
    SELECT studentID
    FROM   tableName
    WHERE  Service IN ('A', 'C')
    GROUP BY StudentID
    HAVING COUNT(studentID) = 2
) a
```

Comment: @Marin . . . This is the right approach for answering your questions.  Use the HAVING clause to define the characteristics you want in your various groups.

Comment: This one works thanks. What about " How many students have signed up for service 'b' and two other services other than 'b' ". Would that be similar to this ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
select COUNT(t.STUDENTID)
from 
(select studentid, service  from table group by STUDENTID having COUNT(service) = 2) as t
WHERE t.service = 'a'
```

Comment: Hi Dan, For some reason it throws an error around Where. Execting AS,ID or quoted_ID it says. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can self join

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT studentid) n
FROM      table t1
LEFT JOIN table t2 on (t1.studentid = t2.studentid)
WHERE t1.service = 'a' AND t2.service <> 'a'
```

or if you want to know the students...

```
SELECT studentid, SUM(IF(service = 'a',1,0)) n_a, SUM(IF(service = 'a',0,1)) n_other
FROM table
GROUP BY studentid
HAVING n_a = 1 AND n_other >= 1
```

Comment: Hi Matt, Thanks for your input. I get ambiguous column studentid (first line) when I try to run it...